# How to add class to form input field?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.2

I am trying to add **jscolor** to an input field but it is not working with me!

**In configure function:**

```
public function configure() {
        unset($this['created_at'],$this['clicks']);
        $this->widgetSchema['background_color']->sfWidgetFormInput('class'=> 'jscolor');
}
```

I also tried adding the below in **BaseForm**:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
            'id'            => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
            'background_color'  => new sfWidgetFormInput(array('class'=> 'jscolor')),
            'url_link'      => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
            'status'        => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
        ));
```

Error: Class is not allowed in the sfWidgetFormInput function !

I want to add a class jscolor! How can i add it via JavaScript or using this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your class to your input during rendering the form element in your template as :

```
<?php echo $form['background_color']->render(array('class' => 'jscolor')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `sfWidgetFormInput` (really, any symfony1 widget) takes 2 parameters - `$options`, and `$attributes`.  You are passing the class as an option rather than as an attribute. Adding the class attribute when you call `render()` in the template is one option, but I would probably opt (in most cases) to do it when setting up the form, in the configure method

```
public function configure() {
        unset($this['created_at'], $this['clicks']);

        $this->setWidget('background_color', new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('class'=> 'jscolor'));

        // or to be a bit more minimalistic:
        $this->getWidget('background_color')->setAttribute('class','jscolor');
}
```

The baseForm is probably autogenerated, and I would strongly recommend against modifying it.